# Proving this map is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a ring and let $J$ be a left ideal of $R$. Let $s \in R$.

We can make the module $R/J$. Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\ann}{ann}\ann_R(t + J) = {\{r \in R : rt + J = 0}\}$ be the annihilator.

I want to show that there is an injective homomorphism $$\theta : R/\ann_R(t + J) \rightarrow R/J$$.

Now, I defined the map to be $\theta(r + \ann_R(t + J)) = r + J$, and showed it was a homomorphism.

I'm having trouble showing it's injective. I tried to show that the kernel was trivial, like so;

$\ker(\theta) = {\{r + \ann_R(t + J) \in R/\ann_R(t + J) : r + J = 0}\}$. So it is the elements $r + \ann_R(t + J)$ such that $r \in J$. To show this is trivial we could show $J \subseteq  \ann_R(t + J)$, as then it would just be elements of the form $0 + \ann_R(t + J)$, which is the zero in the module  $R/\ann_R(t + J)$, but I don't see that this is true?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the $R$-module morphism
$$ \alpha : R  \to R / J, \ \ \  \alpha(r) = (rt + J).$$

Notice that the kernel of $\alpha$ is $ {\rm ann}_R(t + J)$; this is true by the definition of ${\rm ann}_R(t + J)$.

Hence $\alpha$ descends to an injective $R$-morphism $\theta$, whose domain is the quotient space $R / {\rm ker}(\alpha)$:
$$ \theta : R / {\rm ann}_R(t + J) \to R / J, \ \ \ \theta(r + {\rm ann}_R(t+J)) = (rt + J).$$
I believe this is the $\theta$ that you were looking for. It's slightly different from the $\theta$ that you  introduced  in your question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!

Comment: The kernel of $]alpha$ is $J$ not $ann_R (t + J)$. I guess that in general the answer to the question is No.

Comment: @R.C.Cowsik Consider the case where $R = \mathbb Z$, $J = \mathbb Z_4$ and $t = 2$. So $\alpha(r) = [2r]_{\mathbb Z_4}$. The kernel of $\alpha$ is $\mathbb Z_2$, which is the same thing as ${\rm ann}_{\mathbb Z}([2]_{\mathbb Z_4})$.